# How to make Mongoose throw an error when pulling an entry via findByIdAndUpdate() does not find anything in the db?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I'm new to mongodb and node.js. I have the following abbreviated schema:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  },
  likes: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
      }
    }
  ],...
```

I want to access each Post by id (passed through request params) and then remove a like based on the user id. Presently, it removes the like from the array but does not then throw any errors when I try again to remove the same id from the db. Here is my code at the moment:

```
const like = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      { $pull: { likes: { user: req.user.id } } },
      (error, result) => {
        if (!error) {
          return res.json('Post unliked');
        }
        return res.status(400).send('You have not liked this post');
      }
    );
```

Comment: Why do you want to throw an error?  when there is no like to remove?

Comment: Or when there is no post?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I suppose I don't necessarily want an error, I just want some sort of feedback that it hasn't been able to find the like from this user so I can send a different response

Comment: Are you sure about this callback `(error, result)`. I took a look at a book I have about mongo, this what you are doing is mongo, no mongoose, there is no callback.

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate here is the doc for the mongoose function findByIdAndUpdate()

Comment: One suggestion is: after you apply the function you apply, just check the size of the likes array: if it is smaller, something was removed!

Comment: That's a good idea! Thanks!

Comment: another option is: apply `ForEach` on the likes arrays, when you find it, remove! if you do not find it, so you can create a response. See here: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/javascript-array-some-vs-every-vs-foreach-knowledge-scoops-81dfe43369c6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the correct post with findById() instead of findByIdAndUpdate and use the higher order function map() to access the specific index of the like with the required user property.

```
await Post.findById(req.params.id, async (error, result) => {
      if (!error) {
        const index = result.likes
          .map(like => {
            return like.user;
          })
          .indexOf(req.user.id);

        if (index > -1) {
          console.log('found');
          //was found
          result.likes.splice(index, 1);
          await result.save();
          return res.json('Post unliked');
        } else {
          console.log('not found');
          return res.status(400).send('You have not liked this post');
        }
      }
      return res.json(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Id doesn't exist's then it return null so you can check if it return null then you can send the response with status 400 else you can send response with status 200. I think this can be the solution to your problem
hope it work, thanks!

Comment: "If the Id doesn't exist's then it return null ". Where does it return? o result?

Comment: if you console.log result you can see it

Comment: I am not sure about it. Result is the document, the whole document.

Comment: before removing you can check that id exist or not if if not then you can return error else success (here if the id don't exist it will return null) can check

Comment: indeed, it is also a nice idea! he can use  something like `Every()` to make sure they are all different, or at least one is equal!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, and please let me know if it works:

```
 await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id, (error, result) => {
        if (!error) {//if error
          return res.json(error);
        }

         const index = result.likes.indexOf(`${req.user.id}` )//find the index, I am not sure if you will need to add it as a string, make some tests!   

     if (index > -1) {//was found
       result.likes.splice(index, 1);//remove
       result.save();//save the doc to mongo
       return res.json('Post unliked');

        } 
      else  return res.status(400).send('You have not liked this post');// it was not found
      }
    );
```

You may need to adjust something since I am writing the code from my head!

I hope that helps!

References:

1. [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)
2. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp
3. [Mongoose indexOf in an ObjectId array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063587/mongoose-indexof-in-an-objectid-array) <- **this one explains that indexof do work for mongoose ids!**

Comment: Thanks Jorge, will try this tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Hi Jorge, this response led me to the correct answer. I had to use findById() instead of findByIdAndUpdate and I had to use the higher order function map() to access the specific index of the like with the correct user property. I'm going to update this post with the correct answer. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Okay, glad to help!